# MySQL Query - Get total of sum from three different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `sRecords` with some data and three different tables with multiple rows against each `sRecordID` (PK) and a `fees` column,

**the question is** 
How could I get the `sum` of total fees from all three tables matching with `sRecordID`?

the other three tables are cFees, oFees and iFees having `fees` and `sRecordID` (FK sRecords.sRecordID)

**EDIT**
I already have `sRecordID` so I don't think any `JOIN` will going to work here

Comment: can you provide some sample date or you can provide sql fiddle it more good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.sRecordID,sum(t1.Fees)+sum(t2.Fees)+sum(t3.Fees) `Sum Fees`
from sRecords t
left join cFees t1 on t1.feeid=t.sRecordID
left join oFees t2 on t2.feeid=t.sRecordID
left join iFees t3 on t3.feeid=t.sRecordID
group by t.sRecordID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   sRecords.sRecordID,
   SUM(cFees.fees) + SUM(oFees.fees) + SUM(iFees.fees) as total_fees
FROM sRecords
LEFT JOIN cFees ON sRecords.sRecordID = cfees.sRecordID
LEFT JOIN iFees ON sRecords.sRecordID = ifees.sRecordID
LEFT JOIN oFees ON sRecords.sRecordID = ofees.sRecordID
GROUP BY sRecords.sRecordID
```

Comment: what `GROUP BY 1` will do.

Comment: A way of specifying to group by the first expression (column) in the SELECT list. In this case, sRecordID

Comment: Groups by the first selected colum, in this case `sRecords.sRecordID`  Will update it so that it is more transparent for those unfamiliar with SQL